# How can I order a dictionary list by one specified key with some values being None?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

There is a list like

```
l = [{"n": 1, "m": 3}, {"n": None, "m": 1}, {"n": 3, "m": None}, {"n": None, "m": 0}]
```

And I want to order it by one specified key, `n` for example. 
Besides, some value of the key may be `None`, and I want to leave them at behind

Here's my trial

```
l = [{"n": 1, "m": 3}, {"n": None, "m": 1}, {"n": 3, "m": None}, {"n": None, "m": 0}]

from functools import partial
def order(key, item):
    if item[key]:
        return item[key]
    else:
        return 0
order_key = "n"
r = sorted(l, key=partial(order, order_key), reverse=True)
print(r)
```

Is there a better way to make it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach using `sorted` with a `key`:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: -x['n'] if x['n'] is not None else float('inf'))

[{'n': 3, 'm': None},
 {'n': 1, 'm': 3},
 {'n': None, 'm': 1},
 {'n': None, 'm': 0}]
```

---

Let's check with another example:

```
l = [ {"n":1, "m":3}, {"n":None, "m":1}, {"n":3, "m":None}, {"n":None, "m":0}, 
      {"n":0, "m":0}, {"n":-1, "m":0}]

sorted(l, key=lambda x: -x['n'] if x['n'] is not None else float('inf'))

[{'n': 3, 'm': None},
 {'n': 1, 'm': 3},
 {'n': 0, 'm': 0},
 {'n': -1, 'm': 0},
 {'n': None, 'm': 1},
 {'n': None, 'm': 0}]
```

Answer (score 2):

use a key function that returns a tuple for a double criteria:

```
l = [ {"n":1, "m":3}, {"n":None, "m":1}, {"n":3, "m":None}, {"n":None, "m":0}]

result = sorted(l,key = lambda d : (d["m"] is None,d["m"] or 0))
```

result:

```
>>> result
[{'m': 0, 'n': None},
 {'m': 1, 'n': None},
 {'m': 3, 'n': 1},
 {'m': None, 'n': 3}]
```

Let's clarify how and why it works:

`(d["m"] is None,d["m"] or 0)` is a `tuple`:

- `True` if the value is `None` for the first element, which guarantees that `None` entries are last (negate for the reverse effect)
- the other one is the tiebreaker, with the `or` trick to convert `None` to 0 so it's comparable with other integers without errors (although here it is not needed since first boolean stops the tuple comparison so we could write `(d["m"] is None,d["m"])`)

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [ {"n":1, "m":3}, {"n":None, "m":1}, {"n":3, "m":None}, {"n":None, "m":0}]
newlist = sorted(l, key=lambda k:  (k['n'] is None, k['n'] == 0, k['n']), reverse = True)
print (newlist)
```

output:

```
[{'n': None, 'm': 1}, {'n': None, 'm': 0}, {'n': 3, 'm': None}, {'n': 1, 'm': 3}]
```